# How to aggregate the value from DISTINCT row using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, distinct-values

I have following data:

```
Name    Priority
A       3
A       5
B       1
C       1
C       3
C       2
```

I want to get list of distinct names with All priority, so the result

would look like:

```
Name    priorities
A       3,5
B       1
C       1,3,2
```

How can I use Linq to do that?

Comment: What about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__) of GroupBy

```
var grouped = myList.GroupBy(i => i.Name, i => i.Priority, 
    (Name, Priorities) => new {Name, Priorities});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Replay https://stackoverflow.com/users/133910/yuriy-faktorovich, if I Have Multiple Column Aggregate columns for Gruop by How can I use Linq to do?

Comment: @mohammadrg instead of `i => i.Name` use `i => new {i.ColumnA, i.ColumnB...}`